# Selenium Standalone server NodeJS, remote browsers

Tags: node.js, selenium

I'm trying to set up a selenium test environment but having a little trouble due to the fact my browsers are launched remotely via a virtualization launcher service. The path looks something like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client\sfttray.exe" /launch "Mozilla Firefox 32 32.0.0.5350"

My problem, as you can probably guess, is that the server can't find the PATH of my browser binaries. I'd also like to direct it to find my webdrivers (IEDriver.exe, Chromedriver.exe, etc.) which would be nice.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Is there a way to set this up through NodeJS so my co-workers don't have to configure their launch setup individually too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for chrome when launching the hub or node command line use this flag:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER
```

where PATH_TO _CHROMEDRIVER is the directory where you put chromeDriver. For me its /vagrant/bin/chromedriver giving:

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/vagrant/bin/chromedriver
```

For the binaries- in java it looks like you can use this:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/binary"));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Comment: That fixes the issue for my driver not being found, but I still get a "cannot find binary" issue (which I assume is the browser binary).

Comment: Can you add the path to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: I cannot, plus that would mean a different setup for each machine. The solution for this in IE was to use the driver path AND extractPath to the folder I DID have full rights to. I haven't tested to see if chrome has the extractPath parameter yet as well.

Comment: @Organiccat - Did you find solution to this? We are also facing same issue.

Comment: I had to ask for the browsers I needed to test on to be installed locally on my machine. Your devops should provide if they want you to actually do the testing.